# React throws error while using map function to render array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my react application throws error when i am using map function.
The similar code seems to be working fine when i use it in sandbox.

 Error: `ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch`
So, After creating react project, the error is gone. but, when i use map function, it doesn't show anything. localhost:3000 is blank. but, when i comment out **createEmojiCard** function and use the same code inside app function. it works fine.

sample code:

```
import emojis from "../emojipedia";

function createEmojiCard(emoji){
  return(  <dl className="dictionary">
          <div className="term">
          <dt>
            <span className="emoji" role="img" aria-label="Tense Biceps">
              
            </span>
            <span>Tense Biceps</span>
          </dt>
        </div>
  </dl>
  );
}
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        <span>emojipedia</span>
      </h1>
      {emojis.map(createEmojiCard)}
```

Comment: Seems to be a setup problem. Maybe you are running the app from the wrong root directory?

Comment: nope,  directory is fine. it seem to happening only when i am using map

Comment: The error mentions too many file watchers. That is unrelated to `map()`. To help you better we need more info on how you set up your project, and how you open it in VS Code. Perhaps you downloaded the whole project setup `package.json` from CodeSandbox? In that case just throw away the whole CodeSandbox setup and create a fresh new React project. Then paste your own components in there.

Comment: hey i created new react project and tried testing same files. now i don't get the error in terminal. but, i don't see my output on localhost:3000. i will update the question with my whole code.

Comment: I copy>pasted your code into CodePen and there it works: https://codepen.io/eerk/pen/RwMxQVz   But you do have to check that `import emojis from "../emojipedia";` actually returns an array . You could use `console.log(emojis)` to see what's in there.

Comment: the issue seem to be with object. emojipedia have js object like [ const emojipedia = [
  {
    id: 1,
    emoji: "",
    name: "Tense Biceps",
    meaning:
      "“You can do that!” or “I feel strong!” Arm with tense biceps. Also used in connection with doing sports, e.g. at the gym."
  }
when i console log in app function it prints - [object Object], and that's why createEmojiCard is not being triggered.. i don't know why it is printing pbject - object instrad of actual imported object. import looks correct,, what else could go wrong?

Comment: Yes console.log() sometimes gives you [Object Object] if you also log other stuff. But the code seems correct... You could try hard-coding your emoji object first, since that works in the Codepen.

Comment: hi, the issue is resolved. there was a issue with the default export. there were two objects with similar name. i corrected it and its working fine..

Answer (score 1):

you can do a dependency update **npm/yarn install**, if it doesn't work maybe many different projects you open in VS Code, close another project and reload your VS Code

Comment: i don't get any error as i created new project but don't see any output with same code.
how vscode is going to create any issue..? not sure about it.